# How do I get the IP of the attacker?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a website which was attacked by a spammer. How do I get the IP address of that spammer, so that I can block that IP?

I am using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no  direct way to find spam attackers. You need to check the Drupal logs, from which you can get the IP address.